# Why won't my jQuery UI autocomplete widget work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have that input that is meant to autocomplete two tags. By the way, the input is appended.

The input being appended

```
htmlsignup += "<input placeholder='Ваш пол' type='text' value='' class='signup_sex_input' name='signup_sex_input' id='signup_sex_input'/><br>";
```

Autocomplete part

```
$(document).on('keyup',"input#signup_sex_input",function(){
(function() {var tags_for_autocomplete = ["Мужской","Женский"];
$("input[name='signup_sex_input']").autocomplete({
      source: tags_for_autocomplete
});
});
});
```

What do you think I am doing wrong? I hooked up the ui library to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to handle the keyup event - autocomplete manages all of this for you:

Try replacing your function with this:

```
$(function() {
    var tags_for_autocomplete = ["Мужской","Женский"];
    $( "#signup_sex_input" ).autocomplete({
      source: tags_for_autocomplete
    });
  });
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yKpJ3/)

*EDIT*

[Working fiddle adding to the DOM with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/yKpJ3/2/)

```
$(function() {
    var htmlsignup = "<input placeholder='Ваш пол' type='text' value='' class='signup_sex_input' name='signup_sex_input' id='signup_sex_input'/><br>";

    $('body').append(htmlsignup);
    var tags_for_autocomplete = ["Мужской","Женский"];
    $( "input[name='signup_sex_input']" ).autocomplete({
      source: tags_for_autocomplete
    });
  });
```

Comment: Yeah, it does work perfectly in fiddle but there is still a problem because it won't work in my website. I believe the problem is that it has been appended, I mean the input element. I know that the appended elements are called using 'on' function. Is there any other way I might use to make the thing work? The input has been appended previously by JQuery.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code that injects the input into the DOM? Make sure you attach the autocomplete handler after you have added to the DOM

Comment: See my edit with working example showing adding to DOM dynamically